# Оптимизация приложения под планшеты

Tags: java, android, android-studio, оптимизация, google-play

Создал и загрузил приложение в маркет. Через несколько часов после публикации пришло уведомление что оно не оптимизировано для планшетов. Как его можно оптимизировать? Внешний вид экранов схематично изобразил на картинке
Что конкретно нужно оптимизировать?
[image: список экранов]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ "оптимизировать приложение под планшеты" - создать в ресурсах папку с квалификатором, например, `values-xlarge` и положить в нее файл `dimens.xml`. В самом файле все размеры переписать под заданный размер экрана. То же самое нужно сделать для папки `drawable` и, возможно, `layout`.

Возможно вам понадобятся квалификаторы `-large`, `-xhpi` или `-sw800`.

Посмотрите про квалификаторы подробнее [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=ru)

При запуске вашего приложения на устройстве, для которых прописан квалификатор, ресурс возьмется из "нужной" папки (будь то язык, размер экрана или его ориентация)

**Upd:** После этого нужно "Загрузить скриншоты для планшетных ПК": Настройка страницы приложения => Описание приложения > Фото (планшетный ПК).

Comment: они есть в приложении, только там совпадают все значения кроме количества столбцов. скорей всего он хочет что-то другое

Comment: как написано в совете: добавьте фотографии (дополнил ответ)

Comment: при публикации загрузил в консоли несколько скринов для 7 и 10 дюймовых планшетов. на момент получения уведомлений в консоли были скрины для телефонов + планшетов и использовались несколько идентификаторов размера устройств sw600 sw800

Comment: значит у вас всё хорошо :) Посмотрите, здесь исчерпывающий совет от Гугл: https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality#google-play

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте еще в манифест приложения:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

должно помочь